# Authentication during connection to websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, websocket

I'm trying to learn websockets, using `SockJS`, `Angular` and `Spring`. The connection, send and receive of the messages works like a charm.

My problem is, with Spring Security. I couldn't make the authentication work during the connection phase, so i'm validating and setting my auth user every time i send a message.

I'm sending my token as part of the URL (I think websockets don't support headers):

```java
// Other code

@MessageMapping("/send/message/{juegoDatos}/{token}")
public void onRecivedMessage(@DestinationVariable String juegoDatos, @DestinationVariable String token, @RequestBody String message) {

   authService.setAuthUser(token);
   template.convertAndSend("/chat", DateFormatterUtil.formatSimpleDate(new Date()) + " " + message);
}
```

Here is my config:

```java
public class WebsocketConfiguration extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


   @Override
   public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
      registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
              .setAllowedOrigins("*")
              .withSockJS();
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
      registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
              .enableSimpleBroker("/chat");
   }
```

There is any way to override my connection endpoint?

`localhost:8080/socket`

I'm thinking that, maybe i can send my token as URL to it and make the authentication only once. (Actually, if i could override the connection endpoint, i could even make chat rooms and other things)

Thank you!